# i3/sway - How to bindsym minus and equal sign

Tags: i3

I want to map the pactl volume control to:

**$mod+(equal sign)** to increase volume and

**$mod+(minus sign)** to decrease volume

But sway doens't take **$mod+=**, it writes: *Unknown key or button '='* (the same is with the minus sign)

Answer (score 4):

You can bindsym equal using `bindsym $mod+equal` and minus using `bindsym $mod+minus`

you can then increase/decrease the volume by *5%* with pactl by:

```
bindsym $mod+equal exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +5%
bindsym $mod+minus exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -5%
```

For other keys, you can find the key symbol name by installing:

- `xev` if running i3
- `wev` if running sway

Running either of these programs *from the terminal* will open up a new window, and any events captured by that window (e.g. mouse moves, key presses etc.) will be printed in the terminal.

For example, I have sway installed.  If I run `wev` and press the equal sign key I get:

```
[14:     wl_keyboard] key: serial: 31683; time: 272340704; key: 21; state: 1 (pressed)
                      sym: equal        (61), utf8: '='
```

where the key symbol is given by the *sym* field.

when running `xev`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x600001,
    root 0x2a0, subw 0x0, time 272462577, (372,40), root:(1179,512),
    state 0x0, keycode 21 (keysym 0x3d, equal), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3d) "="
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3d) "="
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

where the symbol is given by the second value in the *keysym* field.

Comment: It's worth noting: if you are running sway, you can still use `xev` - thanks to the XWayland support